# Estimating the radius of a circle

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, statistical-inference

I have a circle iwth radius $r$. I want to test the hypothesis that $r \leq 2$ vs. $r >2$ based on the posterior of $r$. $r$ follows the prior distribution: $f(r) = \frac{2}{r^{2}}$, $ r >0.5$. I observed the following points $(x,y): (1,3), (2,1), (0.5,1.4)$. My question is What should be the likelihood?

Edited:
The center of the circle is (0,0)

Comment: For clarity, nothing is known apriori about the center of the circle?

Comment: If you know 3 points, you determine a circle and its center.

Comment: The center is (0;0). I think the point here is trying to use some probability and bayesian inference to solve the problem, not to solve by geometry.

Comment: The way I read your problem, you have a random sample of three points drawn from the interior of an unknown circle (the distribution being presumably uniform).  If the center were known to be the origin, the given sample excludes the possibility of radius $r$ being less than 2.  Perhaps I've fundamentally misunderstood the question.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano:  You describe the prior distribution of radius $r$ as $f(r) = 2/r^2$ for $r \gt 0.5$, but I suspect this should have been $f(r) = \frac{1}{2} r^{-2}$ on $[0.5,+\infty)$.  Would you check?

Comment: The function is right. Why do you suspect that is it wrong? The function I gave you is the same that passed to me. But, if it's wrong, I can verify this.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano:  The integral of a probability density function, which I assume is what is meant by $f(r)$ giving the prior distribution on radius, should be 1.  But the function $2/r^2$ on $[0.5,+\infty)$ gives integral 4.

Comment: Oh yes. But I think that this function it's not normalized, so the integral will not be equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

The observed data implies $r^2\ge3^2+1^2=10$, so $r\ge\sqrt{10}$. Thus the hypothesis $r\le2$ has already been refuted. The likelihood function for $r$ is now $f(r)=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{r^2}$ for $r\ge\sqrt{10}$ and $0$ otherwise.